# Grammar of the poem "When Tomorrow Starts Without Me"

Tags: verbs

In When Tomorrow Starts Without Me , there are two sentences which are like this:

> And when I thought of worldly things I might miss, come tomorrow.
>
> I thought of you, and when I did, my heart was filled with sorrow.

I want to know in the second sentence, where it says "come tomorrow", is this some kind of a method to write a poem (with two verbs in one sentence)?

Comment: There is actually a comma after *miss* and not after *things*. https://books.google.it/books?id=LGGuFRnUFEEC&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=And+when+I+thought+of+worldly+things,+I+might+miss+come+tomorrow,+I+thought+of+you,+and+when+I+did,+my+heart+was+filled+with+sorrow.&source=bl&ots=eKSr7J85b2&sig=GOXjInavKqeCBOldFar9fOxHXYI&hl=it&sa=X&ei=Bgs6VdSjEYbMPfnEgdgI&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=And%20when%20I%20thought%20of%20worldly%20things%2C%20I%20might%20miss%20come%20tomorrow%2C%20I%20thought%20of%20you%2C%20and%20when%20I%20did%2C%20my%20heart%20was%20filled%20with%20sorrow.&f=false

Comment: *And when I thought of worldly things I might miss, come tomorrow. I thought of you  and when I did, my heart was filled with sorrow*.

Comment: "come tomorrow" simply means "when it will be tomorrow". It's a poetic way of just saying _tomorrow_. Maybe that helps in understanding the whole sentence?

Comment: 'When tomorrow comes / gets here' shows the tie-in more clearly. 'When tomorrow gets here' would be stylistically inappropriate here. The full stop in the original is arguably incorrect; a comma would be expected, but then we have clutter. An ellipsis or zero punctuation are better.

Comment: *tomorrow comes* may sound more grammatical, but the poet needed a word to rhyme with *sorrow*.

Comment: OP seems to worry that the sentence contains two verbs (*miss* and *come*, perhaps?). He may be under the impression that sentences may only include a single verb. This situation may have been exacerbated by the mis-transcripted version of the poem lacking the intermediate comma, so that *miss* and *come* are directly adjacent (juxtaposed). Anyway, @ALAN: the quote is certainly poetic, for the obvious reasons and the less-obvious ones Josh, Edwin, and oerkelens have been discussing, but *no*, there was no need to take any special poetic license to use two verbs in a single sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Come` is not a verb here, but a preposition.

From [oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/come):

> preposition
>
> *informal*  When a specified time is reached or event happens:
>
> I don’t think that they’ll be far away from honours come the new
>   season